# Making secure "private site areas" using quasi-serverless web architecture (AJAX templating magic)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

first of all, sorry if my English doesn't sounds very well, I'll try to be as clear as possible.
I'm planning to develop a web site with the following architecture:

Static pages served to the clients that uses javascript templates and ajax to load content, the content will be provided via a ASP.NET MVC application that sends json results to the client pages.

My question is fairly simple: what methods can i use to provide private areas to my site's users?

The only thing that came up in my mind is to provide a login page that sends login info (crypted) to the server (via ajax). Then the server returns a token to be stored as cookie. For every following call to the server via ajax (speaking of private areas now) the token shuold be sent as well, and checked, and proper content result should be provided.

How can i implement this thingy? What are the security and privacy issues?

By the way, i'm using C# in the server, JQuery for simple ajax management and Jquery.LoadJSON for content loading. Mustache for javascript to provide things such partials and so on. I'm looking for something that lets me manage cookie in a simple and clear way as well, suggestions are appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use in-built ASP.NET Authentication mechanism:

- Allow anonymous access to all your pages (assuming that is the requirement).
- Maintain a variable in java-script (client side) to tell if user has been authenticated or not.
- For accessing any secure content/area, call a common js function that will see if current user is authenticated or not and if not then do appropriate action for authenticating the user.
- If its a forms based authentication then your function should prompt user for credentials using a modal dialog and then pass these credentials to server via ajax call. On server side, you should validate credentials and use [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxb3b282.aspx) to indicate successful authentication to ASP.NET run-time. The run-time will maintain the auth cookie (so that you don't have to manage the token by yourself)
- For any ajax call servicing the secure content, on server side, the call must check if the current user is authenticated or not (using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`). If not then you can redirect to error page or issue 401 response code (recommended for windows authentication schemes). You can add any authorization scheme in your AJAX call for the authenticated users.

Comment: also, you can only 'serve' a particular js file if the user has authenticated. so initially, you could serve a basic 'common.js' file and then if the user authenticates, conditionally include a 'leve2-access.js' file which had additional functionality that ws only available to authenticated users.

Comment: Quite a nice solution, I didn't think of using the asp.net built-in authentication management for only the "server side" part of the authentication, i thought it just wouldn't work. For the other side (the client side) i also found this nice little piece of code: